# How Equal-Maturity Option Prices Vary with strike

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

Suppose the current price of a stock $X$ is $40$ and we are considering two $3$-month puts on $X$, strikes $K$ and $K+1$. What would be the upper bound for the price difference of these two puts?

I have tried to compute the difference of payoffs for the cases when $S < K$, $K <S<K+1$, and $S> K +1$.

$p = max(K-S, 0) $

| Scenario | Payoff $P_{K}$ | Payoff $P_{K+1}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $S < K$ | $(K-S)$ | $(K-S)+1$ |
| $K <S<K+1$ | $0$ | $(K-S)+1$ |
| $S> K +1$ | $0$ | $0$ |

How should I proceed to find the upper bound for the price difference of these two puts.

Comment: Well, suppose $K=10000$ say, so you are sure to be selling.  What's the difference in price between the puts?

Comment: Could I approach the question using the following:

Since the price of a put option is Price = Xe^(-rt) *(1-N(d_2)) – P*(1-N(d_1)) with 
P= Price of the security
X= Strike price 
N= standard normal cumulative distribution function 
r =risk-free rate 
v= volatility 
t= time until expiry
d_1 = [ln(P/X) + (r+v2/2)t]/v √t  &  d_2 = d1 – v √t

Then, I take the difference between the Prices of both put options (expressed in terms of the variables above), hoping that as the strike price increases to higher values (for eg 10,000 you mentioned), then the difference would approach 0.

Comment: Nothing in the problem statement suggests that these can be priced via Black Scholes.  This is a more basic question than that.  If you knew for certain that the puts would be exercised, what's the price difference?

Answer (score 1):

For European style put option with a strike price of $k$, interest rate $r$, and time to maturity $T$. We have that it cannot be worth more than the discounted value of the strike price.

$$P \leq k\exp(-rT).$$

Then the upper bound on the on price differences between two puts with different strikes would be the present value of the difference in strike prices

$$(k + 1 - k)\exp(-rT) = \exp(-rT).$$

If the options are American style puts it is just $(k + 1 - k) = 1$, we do not have to discount the value of the difference, because the American puts can be exercised immediately, not just at expiration, if there is a arbitrage opportunity.